# How to turn this formula into an ArrayFormula so it applies down the column

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula that will work when applied to just one cell but stops working when I try to make it an array formula so it applies down the entire column.

I am trying to check if the date in column E is today and if column A is true or false. Based on that, I want column C to read true or false.

I have tried to apply the column to each cell individually by dragging it down, and that works fine. But it will not work with an ArrayFormula.

```
=AND(INT(E2:E)=TODAY(),A2:A=FALSE)
```

When I apply ArrayForumla the result comes back `FALSE` even when it should be positive.

I expect it to automatically populate each cell in the column with that formula and return the correct `TRUE/FALSE` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**G2:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(E3:E), E2:E+F2:F, ))
```

**H2:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((INT(E2:E)=TODAY())+(INT(G2:G)=TODAY()), A2:A, ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you. This is super helpful. It works perfectly but returns the opposite result I need in that column. It reads 'false' instead of 'true'.

Comment: I think i need something like this

'IF D2:D < TODAY( )' leave the cell blank. 

'IF D2:D >= TODAY( ) and A2:A=FALSE' return a value

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18KNAqzQDaniNNtR5sNsmO68gOYYQQ2N6jiWJWByf-8A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: do you want to include 2nd notification into arrayformula if 2nd notif.date falls on today too?

Comment: Yes. 

I'm overcomplicating things. I don't think I need column H for what I am trying to do. 

My goal is to have a script send an email on the date in column G if column A is not checked.

Comment: This seems to only populate column H if one of the dates in either column E or G are todays date.

Comment: isn't that what you wanted? >> "I am trying to check if the date in column E is today and if column A is true or false. Based on that, I want column C to read true or false."

Comment: I misspoke. The column letters have changed. 

I want column H to populate only if column A is FALSE and the date in column G is <= TODAY()

Sorry.

Comment: in that case use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(G2:G), IF((A2:A=FALSE)*(INT(G2:G)<=TODAY()), TRUE), ))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXYq4.png

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=ArrayFormula((A2:A)*(int(D2:D)=TODAY())>0)
```

Comment: Hey! it works! You are amazing. Can you tell me at all what I did wrong? Is this form reading the TRUE/FALSE value as an integer?